# What object does the term "probability distribution" typically refer to, for both discrete and continuous spaces, in different fields of study?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, terminology

In the discrete case, is it taken to refer to a probability mass function (PMF) or a cumulative distribution function (CDF)? Similarly, on continuous probability spaces, is it generally taken to refer to a probability density function (PDF) or a cumulative distribution function (CDF)? Is it used to mean different things in different fields (like probability theory vs. physics vs. engineering), or is there any ambiguity as to the terminology, etc.?

Edit 1: I should have included the option that it could refer to the probability measure or the full description of a probability space.

Edit 2: I have definitely seen scientists and engineers refer to CDFs and PDFs (especially PDFs) as "probability distributions".

Comment: Re: edit 2.  I have seen mathematicians do that as well.  As long as there is no ambiguity, and you don't look for a PDF where there isn't one, there's no problem in doing so.  Context should make clear what is meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the distribution of a (real-valued) random variable $X$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb R$ that assigns each measurable set $E$ the probability $\mathbb P(X \in E)$.  There are various ways you can choose to represent that probability measure, depending on the type of measure it is.  You can always specify its CDF; if it has a PDF or PMF you can specify that.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above. A *proability distribution* is a map $P$ that assigns a number $\in[0,1]$ to each measurable set of a probability space such that $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$ for disjoint $A,B$ and a few other conditions are fulfilled.

A probability mass function or cumulative distribution function or probability density function are *properties* of probability distributions for sufficiently friendly probability spaces.